# How many total functions f : A → A are there?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

So, im quite new to discrete mathematics and I am unsure as to how I would go about approaching the following problem:

Let A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}.

(1) How many total functions f : A → A are there?

(2) How many of the functions in (a) are one-to-one?

For 1, wouldnt there only be 5 functions? also how would i prove / show this. Also if someone could point me to some good informational websites or documents about functions for discrete mathematics that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For (1), you must see that the are five possibilities for the image of each one of the five elements of A, and so there are 5⁵ = 3125  possible functions.

For the functions that are one-to-one, you only have 5! = 120 possible functions, because one you decide which is f(1), you have only four possibilities for f(2), and then three for f(3), and so on.

Answer (score 1):

(1) To define $f$ you must set $f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4) and f(5)$. You have 5 choices for each one so there is $5^5$such fonctions.

(2)You have to chose a value for $f(1)$ you have 5 choices then you have 4 choices to chose $f(2)$ and so on. So there is $5!$ such functions.